# What does npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS mean?

Tags: node.js, npm, serverless

Building a node project, using serverless

Firstly I get the error

```
Error:
Error: npm ls -prod -json -depth=1 failed with code 1
  at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/jrobens/NetBeansProjects/azuron/winpay/winpay-
```

uploader/node_modules/serverless-webpack/lib/utils.js:91:16)

To find our more information I enter *npm ls -prod -json -depth=1* and get

```
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: serverless@3.2.1 
/my-project/node_modules/serverless
{
```

It looks as though webpack worked

```
webpack compiled successfully in 4581 ms
```

About the environment: node-14, typescript, aws

```
├── @serverless/typescript@3.2.0
├── @types/serverless@3.0.0
├── serverless-apigw-binary@0.4.4
├── serverless-certificate-creator@1.6.0
├── serverless-dynamodb-local@0.2.40
├── serverless-http@2.7.0
├── serverless-iam-roles-per-function@3.2.0
├── serverless-plugin-aws-alerts@1.7.4
├── serverless-prune-plugin@2.0.1
├── serverless-s3-local@0.6.21
├── serverless-webpack@5.6.1
```

Comment: Apparently, "E" means "error," "LS" refers to the "ls" or "list" command, and "PROBLEMS"... Beats me :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixing this

```
npm ls -prod json
```

produces a json list of the packages. The -depth=1 flag brought an error to light. There was an invalid package.

Find the invalid package by

```
npm ls
```

and fix any error messages.

In my case there was an old serverless plugin that had a dependency of a different version of serverless.

Comment: `npm ls` didnt list any invalid packages for me.

Comment: if you scroll up the terminal window (or better yet just search the window for the  package name output in the error) you should see a red error message, in my case it said:
`type-fest@0.21.3 deduped invalid: "^0.13.1" from node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin`

Comment: @GiffordN. what should we do with this deduped package? I get similar errors with eslint after uninstalling eslint. But it shows me these errors on react-scripts as third (or 4th) level dependency

Comment: In the case of the above example it was downgrading to an older version of react-scripts to resolve the dependency conflict. `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` might also help

Comment: I had to pass the `-a` flag to see the broken packages: `npm list -a`

Answer (score 4):

I fixed removing packages-lock.json and then doing npm install.
Not sure if this is the best way to fix it, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the first answer, **this problem seems to happen more often when installing packages from the local disk**, ie `npm ls /some/dir/somewhere`.

After I'd installed a package I was working on from the local disk:

```
app@0.0.1 /home/mike/Code/portal/decentralized-ip/app
└─┬ @myorg/packagename@1.0.0 -> ./../../some-dir
  └─┬ ...
    └─┬ ...
      └─┬ @metaplex-foundation/js@0.16.1
        └─┬ @bundlr-network/client@0.7.17
          └─┬ arbundles@0.6.22
            └── avsc@5.4.7 invalid: "https://github.com/Bundlr-Network/avsc#csp-fixes" from ../../svelte-on-solana-wallet-adapter/node_modules/arbundles
```

After **publishing to npm, removing the locally installed version, then installing from npm**, the problem is fixed:

```
app@0.0.1 /home/mike/Code/portal/decentralized-ip/app
└─┬ @myorg/packagename@1.0.0
  └─┬ ..
    └─┬ ...
      └─┬ @metaplex-foundation/js@0.16.1
        └─┬ @bundlr-network/client@0.7.17
          └─┬ arbundles@0.6.22
            └── avsc@5.4.7 (git+ssh://git@github.com/Bundlr-Network/avsc.git#a730cc8018b79e114b6a3381bbb57760a24c6cef)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error then updated angular and that solved it.

```
$ ng update
```